# ieee754 floating point 1/x * x > 1.0

Tags: c, floating-point, ieee-754

I want to know whether the program defined below can return 1 assuming:

- IEEE754 floating point arithmetics
- no overflow (neither in `max/x` nor in `f*x`)
- no nan or inf (obviously)
- 0 < x and 0 < n < 32
- no unsafe math optimization

```
int canfail(int n, double x) {
    double max = 1ULL << n; // 2^n
    double f = max / x;
    return f * x > max;
}
```

In my opinion, it should sometime return 1, as `roundToNearest(max / x)` can in general be greater than `max/x`.
I'm able to find numbers for the opposite case, where `f * x < max`, but I have no examples of input that show `f * x > max` and I have no idea of how to find one. Can somebody help ?

**EDIT**:
I know the value of x if in a range between 10^(-6) and 10^6 (that still leaves a lot (too much possible double values), but I know I will not have to deal with overflow, underflow or sub-normal numbers !
In addition, I just realized that because `max` is a power of two and we don't deal with overflow, **the solution will be the same by fixing `max=1`** as it is exactly the same computation, but shifted.

Therefore, the problem correspond to finding a positive, normal double value `x` such that `(1/x) * x > 1.0 !!

I made a little program to try to find a solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <omp.h>

int main( void ) {
    #pragma omp parallel
    {
        unsigned short int xsubi[3] = {
            omp_get_thread_num(),
            omp_get_thread_num(),
            omp_get_thread_num()
        };

        #pragma omp for
        for(int64_t i=0; i<INT64_MAX; i++) {
            double x = fmod(nrand48(xsubi), 1048576.0);
            if(x<0.000001)
                continue;

            double f = 1.0 / x;
            if(f * x > 1.0) {
                printf("found !!! x=%.30f\n", x);
                fflush(stdout);
            }
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

If you change the sign of the comparison, you will find some value quickly. However, it seems to run forever with `f * x > 1.0`

Comment: What about sub-normal `a` and / or `b`?

Comment: Good question. x cannot be sub-normal, it should be in a "safe range" such that `max / x` never overflow for any value of n below 32.

Comment: Although you mentioned that `1 << n` cannot overflow, you should ensure that you use unsigned type large enough to fit possible bits, for example `1ull << n`.

Comment: I gave more detailed on the constraints on n and added `ull`

Comment: Is `f` allowed to become subnormal?

Comment: Actually, x is a geometric coordinates in my application. f being subnormal would mean that x is abnormally large...

Comment: Quite right, but that doesn't answer my question!

Comment: It's not allowed to be subnormal. I don't deal with sub-normals, infinite, NaN, overflows or underflows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiplication by a power of two is just a scaling of exponent, it does not change the problem: so it's the same as finding `x` such that `(1/x) * x > 1`.

One solution is brute force search.
For same reasons, we can limit the search of such `x` in the interval (1.0,2.0(

A better approach is to analyze error bounds without brute force.

Let's note `ix` the nearest floating point to `1/x`.

Considering `x`and `ix`as exact fractions, we can write the integer division: `1 = ix * x + r` where `r`is the remainder
(these are all fractions with denominators being powers of 2, so we have to multiply the whole equation by appropriate power of 2 to really have integer division).
In other words, `ix = 1/x - r/x`, where `-r/x` is the rounding error of inversion.
When we multiply the inverse approximation by `x`, the exact value is `ix*x = 1 - r`.
We know that the floating point result will be rounded to the nearest float to that exact value.
So, assumming default rounding mode to nearest, tie to even, the question asked is whether `-r` can exceed `0.5 ulp`.

The short answer is never!
Suppose `|r| > 0.5 ulp`, then the rounding error `-r/x` does exceed half ulp of exact result `1/x`.
This is not a proper answer, because the exact result is not a floating point and does not have an ulp, but you get the idea...
I might come back with a correct proof if i have time, but my bet is that you can find it already done, possibly on SO

**EDIT**
Why can you find `(1/x) * x < 1`?

Simply because 1.0 is at a binade limit, so below 1, we have to prove that `r<0.25 ulp`, what we cannot...

Comment: I went to see one of my collegue and we arrived exactly to the same answer !
Just found out your answer coming back to my office.

Comment: "ix the nearest floating point to 1/x" is a good first step.  Yet IEEE754 has rounding modes may differ than round to nearest.  I suspect this answer still holds in other modes, yet may be worthy of investigation to see if a counter-example exists.

Comment: This answer may have been on the right track, but it looks like it went off the rails a bit. We do not want to find an `ix = 1/x - r/x`, where the rounding went downward. We want a case where the rounding goes upward.

Comment: @EricPostpischil yes, unfortunate notations indeed, `r` is signed and interesting case is negative `r`

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica right, I could have mentionned the default rounding mode...

Comment: @chux: Of course it cannot hold when rounding is upward (toward +infinity). An exact division will round upward, and then the product necessarily exceeds the original dividend.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Suggest posting [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59390537/ieee754-floating-point-1-x-x-1-0/59394532?noredirect=1#comment104983392_59394532) then as an example of `printf("found !!! x=%.30f\n", x);` as it appears to be a good answer to OP.

Comment: @yakoudbz also note I have assumed strict ieee754, so of course you have to use appropriate c compiler options that will offer such guaranty (no use of excess precision etc...)

Answer (score 4):

In the absence of underflow or overflow, the exponents are irrelevant; if `M/x*x > M`, then `(M/p) / (x/q) * (x/q) > (M/p)` for any powers of two `p` and `q`. So let’s consider 2<sup>52</sup> ≤ `x` < 2<sup>53</sup> and `M` = 2<sup>105</sup>. We can eliminate `x` = 2<sup>52</sup> since this yields exact floating-point arithmetic, so 2<sup>52</sup> < `x` < 2<sup>53</sup>.

Division of 2<sup>105</sup> by `x` yields integer quotient `q` and integer remainder `r`, with 2<sup>52</sup> `q` < 2<sup>53</sup>, 0 < `r` < `x`, and 2<sup>105</sup> = `q`•`x` + `r`.

In order for `M/x*x` to exceed `M`, both the division and the multiplication must round up. Since the division rounds up, `x`/2 ≤ `r`.

With rounding up, the result of floating-point division of 2<sup>105</sup> by `x` yields `q`+1. Then the exact (not rounded) multiplication yields (`q`+1)•`x` = `q`•`x` + `x` = `q`•`x` + `x` + `r` - `r` = `q`•`x` + `r` + `x` − `r` = 2<sup>105</sup> + `x` − `r`. Since `x`/2 < `r`, `x` − `r` ≤ `x`/2, so rounding this exact result rounds down, yielding 2<sup>105</sup>. (The “<” case always rounds down, and the “=” case rounds down because 2<sup>105</sup> has the low even bit.)

Therefore, for powers of two `M` and all arithmetic within exponent bounds, `M/x*x > M` never occurs with round-to-nearest-ties-to-even.

Comment: See also: Alan Edelman, "When is x ✱(1/x) ≠ 1?" [Online draft](http://www-math.mit.edu/~edelman/homepage/papers/ieee.pdf), December 7, 1994.

Answer (score 1):

canfail(1, pow(2, 1023) * (2 - pow(2, -51))) will return 1.

Comment: 179769313486231550856124328384506240234343437157459335924404872448581845754556114388470639943126220321960804027157371570809852884964511743044087662767600909594331927728237078876188760579532563768698654064825262115771015791463983014857704008123419459386245141723703148097529108423358883457665451722744025579520 is definitely not in the range of number that I consider...

Comment: Please, provide more details about your question.

Comment: Why? the value is representable by IEEE754 double precision format.

Comment: 1.0/(pow(2, 1023) * (2 - pow(2, -51))) = 5.56268464626800345772558179333e-309
           
That is definitely a subnormal number because the smallest normal number is around 1e-38. I wanted a proof involving only normal numbers with no overflow or underflow. I should have been more precise. Anyway, I got two satisfying answers, proving rigorously that it cannot happen with IEE754 round-to-nearest-ties-to-even.

Comment: OK. I understand. But, the smallest normal number of double precision is 2^(-1022) ~= 2.225e-308. 1e-38 is that of single precision. As you say, 5.56e-309 is a subnormal number, and I think that such a phenomenon does not happen in normal number.

Comment: @yakoudbz Re; [t cannot happen with IEE754 round-to-nearest-ties-to-even](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59390537/ieee754-floating-point-1-x-x-1-0#comment105011282_59399582): Although the post talks about `roundToNearest`, the question itself is not restricted to "round-to-nearest-ties-to-even".  Such restrictions in your comment deserved to have been in the original post.

Comment: @yakoudbz Note [the smallest normal number is around 1e-38](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59390537/ieee754-floating-point-1-x-x-1-0#comment105011282_59399582) is amiss.  A `double` with IEEE754  smallest normal is about 2.2250738585072014E-308.

Comment: The answer shows a failed case and meets the 5  bullet-ed point criteria.